# Host name or Domain not found

Tags: postfix

I have installed amavis + postfix + spamassassin on centOS 5.4. The "/etc/hosts"  file contains:

```
127.0.0.1              localhost.localdomain localhost
::1           localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
67.215.65.132          mail.sufalamtech.local mail
```

When I am sending mail, the following error is occured:

```
Apr  8 06:20:53 mail sendmail[3229]: o380oqu7003229: from=root, size=62, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201004080050.o380oqu7003229@mail.sufalamtech.local>, relay=root@localhost
Apr  8 06:20:53 mail postfix/smtpd[3230]: connect from mail.sufalamtech.local[127.0.0.1]
Apr  8 06:20:53 mail sendmail[3229]: STARTTLS=client, relay=[127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Apr  8 06:20:54 mail postfix/smtpd[3230]: 5A53C1A5989: client=mail.sufalamtech.local[127.0.0.1], sasl_sender=root@mail.sufalamtech.local
Apr  8 06:20:54 mail postfix/cleanup[3238]: 5A53C1A5989: message-id=<201004080050.o380oqu7003229@mail.sufalamtech.local>
Apr  8 06:20:54 mail sendmail[3229]: o380oqu7003229: to=admin@sufalamtech.local, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30062, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as 5A53C1A5989)
Apr  8 06:20:54 mail postfix/qmgr[3107]: 5A53C1A5989: from=<root@mail.sufalamtech.local>, size=587, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  8 06:20:54 mail postfix/smtpd[3230]: disconnect from mail.sufalamtech.local[127.0.0.1]
Apr  8 06:20:54 mail postfix/smtp[3240]: 5A53C1A5989: to=<admin@sufalamtech.local>, relay=none, delay=0.63, delays=0.17/0.1/0.36/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=mail.sufalamtech.local type=A: Host not found)
Apr  8 06:20:54 mail postfix/cleanup[3238]: E73C51A5987: message-id=<20100408005054.E73C51A5987@mail.sufalamtech.local>
Apr  8 06:20:54 mail postfix/qmgr[3107]: E73C51A5987: from=<>, size=2594, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  8 06:20:54 mail postfix/bounce[3241]: 5A53C1A5989: sender non-delivery notification: E73C51A5987
Apr  8 06:20:54 mail postfix/qmgr[3107]: 5A53C1A5989: removed
Apr  8 06:20:55 mail postfix/local[3242]: E73C51A5987: to=<root@mail.sufalamtech.local>, relay=local, delay=0.15, delays=0.02/0.1/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Apr  8 06:20:55 mail postfix/local[3242]: warning: host not found: localhost
Apr  8 06:20:55 mail postfix/qmgr[3107]: E73C51A5987: removed
Apr  8 06:21:04 mail postfix/qmgr[3107]: warning: connect to transport amavis: No such file or directory
Apr  8 06:22:04 mail postfix/qmgr[3107]: warning: connect to transport amavis: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try any diagnostics?

What happens if you look it up from the command line:

```
host mail.sufalamtech.local
```

If that comes back with host not found, then you have a problem outside of postfix.
For example, /etc/nsswitch.conf may list only dns as a resolver for hosts
If you want it to use the hosts file, then "files" must appear next to "hosts"
in nsswitch.conf.

If you don't have a problem with the host command, then it can be something in postfix configuration which is triggering a name service lookup.  Are you using a transport file?

On the postfix mailing list, they always ask for people to post the output of their postconf -n , which displays all changes from the default settings in the configuration.

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: ok files is there